# Pass value from input to href with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve the next scenario when user click on the input it passes that value to URL and makes input radio checked, so I can send that URL to someone.

So far I am stuck here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name=semester1]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'semester  1') {
            alert("semestar 1");
        }
        else if (this.value == 'semester  2') {
            alert("Semester 2");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="semester1" id="tab1" value="semester  1" aria-controls="semester  1">
<label for="tab1">semester  1</label>
<input type="radio" name="semester2" id="tab2" value="semester  2" aria-controls="semester  2">
<label for="tab2">semester  2</label>
<input type="radio" name="semester3" id="tab3"  value="semester  3" aria-controls="semester  3">
<label for="tab3">semester  3</label>
```

Idea is to have something like this when you select input

```
localhost/study&semester1
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: When you say 'pass that value to a URL' do you mean by redirecting the page, or by AJAX, or something else entirely? Your goal isn't clear

Comment: Also `localhost/study&semester1` is not a very useful URL, Perhaps you meant `localhost/?study=semester1` or `localhost/study?semester=semester1`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify using jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name=semester]').change(function() {
        const href = $("#click_here").attr("href").split(/=/)
        const link = href[0]+"="+ $(this).val()
        alert(link);
        $("#click_here").attr("href", link)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="semester" id="tab1" value="semester  1" aria-controls="semester  1">
<label for="tab1">semester  1</label>
<input type="radio" name="semester" id="tab2" value="semester  2" aria-controls="semester  2">
<label for="tab2">semester  2</label>
<input type="radio" name="semester" id="tab3"  value="semester  3" aria-controls="semester  3">
<label for="tab3">semester  3</label>

<a id="click_here" href="https://localhost/study?semester=''">click here</a>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you read the question again, as you seemed to have missed the point

Comment: added please check now

Comment: Why generate a url, show it, then set the href to a different url?  Gives `localhost:8080?test,1=semester  1"`

Comment: Write ur logic.. I think that much can be done.. As developer.. It is just example ho to do it

Comment: Done anyways.. Can be checked now

Comment: It now generates url `https://localhost/study/?semester,'' =semester  2` - but the idea is sound

Answer (score -1):

Simply get the reference of anchor field and pass the url to it based on radio click like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let field = document.querySelector('#field');
    let url = "localhost/study&";

    $('input:radio[name=semester1]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'semester  1') {
            url= url+this.value;
            field.attr('href',url )
        }
        else if (this.value == 'semester  2') {
            url= url+this.value;
            field.attr('href',url )
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should test your code with a snippet (copy OPs html).  It doesn't work as `field` is not a jquery object.  I'd also recommend against duplicating the code as adding additional lines makes this difficult to maintain (eg OPs code has 3 entries so your code will not work with 2) - sure that's how OP has it now, but they're they one asking for help.